# In informal, colloquial language, how do you say (rather neutrally) to ask someone to "leave the place"?

Tags: expressions

We were having a conversation in German, and I was wondering how the same idea is commonly/idiomatically expressed in French:

> Willst du was von uns? Wenn nicht, solltest du lieber '**ne Fliege machen**. Wir haben schon genug um die Ohren, ohne dass du uns auf die Nerven gehst. Wah! Wie kommen wir nur wieder aus diesem Schlamassel heraus?

Here I was (jokingly) asking one of our colleagues to **leave the place**, **leave us alone** for now. In German, the expression "*'ne Fliege machen*", coupled with the polite turn of phrase "*solltest du lieber*", can convey this idea without coming across as particularly rude or annoyed, as in "Clear off!".

In French, perhaps I'd have said:

> Tu cherches quelque chose ? Si c’est pas le cas, tu ferais bien de **déguerpir**. On a déjà assez à faire sans que tu viennes nous casser les pieds. Aaah, comment on va s’en sortir ?

Does "*déguerpir*" fit the bill here? If I say the following, on the other hand, I wonder if it carries a rather 'annoyed' tone, as in "*Will you kindly ...?*" or "*gefälligst*"?

> On est occupés, **va** donc **voir ailleurs si on y est**.

Comment: *Déguerpir* and *aller voir ailleurs* are both rude. The conditional wouldn't help moderate them.

Answer (score 2):

I would say :

> Est-ce que tu as besoin de quelque chose ? **Car nous sommes un peu occupés pour le moment.**

You do not need to explicitly tell the person to leave :)
You could also add :

> Peux-tu repasser un peu plus tard ?

Answer (score 0):

To me, the most neutral way to say it is:

> Pourrais-tu partir s'il te plait ?

Answer (score 0):

Asking someone to *déguerpir* sounds a bit like a threat.  *Va voir ailleurs si j'y suis!* to me is a bit rude.  To convey annoyance at somebody's continued presence in my company, maybe I'd say : *T'as vraiment rien d'autre à faire !?*

Comment: I tend to think that the example you give here especially shows some annoyance.

Answer (score 0):

> On est occupés, tu pourrais partir s'il te plaît ?
>
> On est occupés, tu pourrais nous laisser s'il te plaît ?

Ce dernier est plus poli mais reste clair.

"*Déguerpir*" et "*aller voir ailleurs si j'y suis*" sont assez fort, la personne risque de mal le prendre.

Comment: Est-ce que "déguerpir" n'en reste pas moins '*fort*', même avec le conditionnel "tu ferais bien" ?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Bon déjà "déguerpir" est assez vieilli, et il est quasiment plus utilisé à l'oral, et ensuite, je pense pas que ça change grand-chose. Les autres options qui me viennent en tête c'est "*T'as intérêt à déguerpir*", c'est juste pas envisageable de dire "*Déguerpis !*" (idiomatique mais beaucoup trop daté)

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens D'ailleurs, je me demande. Ça t'arrive de proposer des phrases avec des mots qui me paraissent datés et que j'ai pas entendu dans les 10 dernières années. Est-ce que c'est des mots que tu as entendu à l'oral ou uniquement lus ? Le registre oral en français est vraiment différent du registre écrit, et c'est peut-être mieux d'utiliser que des mots que tu as déjà entendu à l'oral je pense.